# Create ejabberd user

Tags: mysql, macos, ejabberd

I'm running macOS High Sierra and attempting to get ejabberd up and running with mysql.

I have installed both ejabberd and mysql both with homebrew for simplicity.

However, I am getting the finger from mysql.  I have secured my mysql installation with a password and tightened it down to only localhost access.  I can log into mysql via command line but the following commands do not appear to execute.  I end up with an arrow prompt after each command.

```
echo "GRANT ALL ON ejabberd.* TO 'ejabberd'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';" | mysql -h localhost -u root

echo "CREATE DATABASE ejabberd;" | mysql -h localhost -u ejabberd -p
```

I've replaced 'password' in the first command with 'j@ber' for grins and giggles.

I need help.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps you, this is what I do in the test server:

```
mysql -u root -pthisisrootpassword
CREATE USER ejabberd_test IDENTIFIED BY 'ejabberd_test';
CREATE DATABASE ejaup;
GRANT ALL ON ejaup.* TO "ejabberd_test"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "ejabberd_test";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
\q
mysql -u ejabberd_test -pejabberd_test ejaup < sql/mysql.sql
```

Then in ejabberd.yml

```
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejaup"
sql_username: "ejabberd_test"
sql_password: "ejabberd_test"
```